# pgagent no jobs appearing

Tags: postgresql, pgagent

I'm trying this one more time:

I have an installation of PostgreSQL 12 on my local Windows machine.  I have a database set up, and I have installed PG Agent.  I can see also see PG Agent in PG Admin, and I've set up jobs with steps.  Everything looks like it's set up correctly, but when I go to run the job and then run `select * from pgagent.pga_joblog` - the query returns nothing.  I'm not sure why the jobs are failing.

I've run the following query to get log locations:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    pg_settings 
WHERE
    --name like '%agent%'
   category IN( 'Reporting and Logging / Where to Log' , 'File Locations')
ORDER BY 
    category,
    name;
```

But I just get these:

[image]

I'm not really sure what else to try.  Can anyone help?